# Terminal command in Applescript not working

Tags: applescript

I am trying to get a terminal command to work in Applescript and I get the error "Expected end of line but found identifier." How can I fix this?

This is my code

```
try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'; killall Dock" with administrator privileges
end try
```

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't use some special characters (e.g. `"` or `\`) between the quotation marks after the `do shell script` part of Apple Scripts or you have to escape them with a back slash.

In your example the second quotation mark is interpreted as the end of the shell command: `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{` which is no valid line.

So escape the inner quotation marks with a back slash and your Apple Script should work:

```
try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{\"tile-type\"=\"spacer-tile\";}'; killall Dock" with administrator privileges
end try
```

If you have a shell command like this:

```
... awk '/disk/ {gsub("\"",""); print $NF}' ...
```

you would have to escape each `"` and `\` with a back slash:

```
try
    do shell script "... awk '/disk/ {gsub(\"\\\"\",\"\"); print $NF}' ..."
end try
```

Comment: @user3439894 Good question - though not related to the question here. I just copied [a part of an AppleScript answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207103/93229) containing a lot of `"`s and back slashes.

Comment: @user3439894 I have tested it. The $ is obligatory in the context of my answer to Tetsujin's question! Now I have to explain it :-O... With NF i get a `10` and with $NF I get `disk2` and I needed some `diskX`result!